# Why does 老舍 in《猫城记》 use the phrase 不是没有 in 因为不是没有阳光?

Tags: meaning-in-context, emphasis

> 远处有些小山，也是灰色的，比天空更深一些；**因为不是没有阳光**，小山上是灰里带着些淡红，好像野鸽脖子上的彩闪。
> <sub>猫城记，老舍, p.7 ([photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJfzx.jpg); [alt](https://gcdnb.pbrd.co/images/b6KDlq66Xwgd.jpg))</sub>

I'd translate this to:

> In the distance there are some small mountains, which are also gray, darker than the sky; **因为不是没有阳光**, the grayness on small mountains brings with it some redness, like the glistening of a wild dove's neck.

It feels like the double negative used in 因为不是没有阳光 is intended to say something like "because there's still a wee bit of sun", equivalent to something like 还略有阳光.  I'm unclear on this point.

**Question**: Why does 老舍 in《猫城记》 use the phrase 不是没有 in 因为不是没有阳光?

Comment: Are you translating Lao She(老舍)'s Chinese version of "Cat City Chronicles"(《猫城记》) into an English edition?

Comment: No, I'm just reading it (again).  I translated this part to indicate my level of understanding.

Comment: Is English your native language?

Answer (score 2):

Semantically, "not without sunshine" and "slightly sunny" have the same meaning. In my opinion, using double negative here, is for expressing and emphasizing the feeling of "not dark". It has a slightly different feeling from "a bit of sun".

Answer (score 1):

I think to be better understand `因为不是没有阳光`, considering the context. I found a vocabulary word that can help us better understand. In chinese is **淡红**, in English is redness,  "淡红" can be understood as a slightly reddish color(淡红可以理解成有一点红或者有一丝丝红). Don't forget that the sun is red in color.

So I think change `因为不是没有阳光` to `因为不是没有一点阳光` may be can easily understand.

`因为不是没有一点阳光` means 还是有一点阳光(there is still a little bit of sunshine), 就是这一点阳光导致了小山上是灰里带着些**淡红**(result to "the grayness on small mountains brings with it some **redness**").

I think you already understand this sentence now.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this was what he wanted to say with a style of his own.

天空是灰矇矇的, 遠山看來更灰暗, 但偶ㄦ破云而出的陽光照耀在小山上, 使其看來灰裡帶紅....

- 不是沒有阳光, 是它躲在云層後, 時隱時現.